# Directive fails in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which renders an image as a background image.  It works great in Chrome and Safari (as far as I can tell) but seems to not work in Firefox (the background-images don't show up).
My research seems to indicate that maybe scope.$watch would help, but I'm not entirely sure how to apply it so that it will make things better.

```
.directive('pictures', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       var url = attrs.pictures;
                element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + url +')',
            'background-size' : 'cover'
          });
      }
    };
  });
```

Help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What´s your Firefox version?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was, strangely enough, adding "display:block" to the img tag css. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your messing with `"` in `background-image` url property.

**Code**

```
.directive('pictures', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       var url = attrs.pictures;
                element.css({
            'background-image': 'url("' + url +'")', <-- Change here
            'background-size' : 'cover'
          });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: @beardedmike could I know what is your url?

Answer (score 0):

If the value in the `pictures` attribute is being set asynchronously then you should use `scope.$watch` to watch it and set the background image after the attribute value has been set. It might have just been lucky timing that the value was already set in Chrome and Safari when your directive's `link` function ran.

So if your markup looks something like this:

```
<div class="pic" pictures="images[0].imageUrl"></div>
```

where your `images` array is populated via an AJAX call, then your directive would look something like this:

```
.directive('pictures', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

       // attrs.pictures probably not set at this point so $watch it

       scope.$watch(attrs.pictures, function (newVal, oldVal) {
         if (!newVal || (newVal === oldVal)) {
           return;
         }

          element.css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + newVal +')',
            'background-size' : 'cover'
          });

       });
    }
  };
});
```

[Here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pqbf6WRK8YjvR50BtIMb?p=preview).